# Media Picker Items's Plus Button Not Animated When Pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

My app calls iOS' native MPMediaPicker during music selection for its playlist.

Code:

```
// show media picker
MPMediaPickerController *picker =
[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

picker.delegate                     = self;
picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But during the selection, which is below screen:

[image]

when you tap on the "+" buttons of songs, the button doesn't animate (like becoming grey, highlighted, etc), so the user has no feedback that the button was successfully tapped.

I did not observe this in iOS 7.0, but after I upgraded to iOS 8, this problem showed up.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to iOS 9, I noticed that the problem was fixed (at least for my app).

Answer (score 0):

This issue seemed to arise around iOS 8.4 and seems to still exist in iOS 9.0 final.

The bug has apparently been reported to Apple and should hopefully be fixed in a later release. Fingers crossed.

More info at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9758

Edit: Update - Seems the situation with this bug is proving "complicated" according to the Apple team member at that link above. Can I suggest that of anyone is experiencing this bug, please report it to Apple as an iOS 9 bug.